# Mutli directionnal slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I'm looking for a slider like this one: [Demo: plus mûrs](http://plusmurs.fr/)
[image]

So several slider on top of each other, when you are done with all the images of slider 1, it directly goes to slider 2, you can also scroll, and it also goes to slider 2. I don't know if it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can change you x and y scroll position based on image size or screen size calculation.
So it will give same effect, i assume.

## Code:-

```
window.scrollBy(0,50) 
50 is the amount of pixels you want to scroll by.
```